# Deriving Barometric formula

Tags: calculus, physics

*Recall idea gas law: $pV= NkT$ where $p$ equals pressure, V volume, N moles of atoms, k boltzmann's constant, T temperature.
Also, density: $\rho = m/V = \mu N/N_A V$ where $\mu$ is average mole mass and $N_A$ is Avogadro's number.
Use these equations to show that as we go up in the atmosphere, pressure is given by:
$$p = p_o e^{ \frac{ \mu g h }{N_A k T}}$$*

I'm pretty lost here. I tried checking out some wikipedia articles but I don't get how $e$ ever appears while deriving this formula!

Comment: You are missing a minus sign in the exponent.  Pressure should decrease with altitude.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is to consider a volume element of unit transverse area and vertical extent $dh$.  Gravity exerts a downward force on the volume of $g \rho V=g \rho 1^2 dh$.  This needs to be balanced by an upward force, and the only one available is more pressure on the bottom than on the top.  So $p(h)1^2=p(h + dh)1^2+g\rho 1^2 dh, \frac {dp}{dh}(h)=-g\rho(h)$  The ideal gas law now says $\rho \propto p$ so you get a differential equation $\frac {dp}{dh}=-kp$ with solution $p=c e^{-kh}$.  That is where the $e$ comes from.

Comment: I think our physics teacher must be grossly overestimating our mathematical abilities. We haven't learned differential equations yet.

Comment: Can you tell me on a side-note...I'm calculating the pressure 919 meters up and the chemical composition of the atmosphere is: $21$ percent $O_2$ and $78$ percent $N_2$. Does this mean that I say: $O_2 = 32$ atomic mass and $N_2 = 28$ Atomic mass, so $0.21 \cdot 32 + 0.78 \cdot 28 = 28,56 = \mu$, the average mole mass?

Comment: You need to add in the $1\%$ Argon, but you are doing the right thing.  These constituents are for dry air, so to be really right you have to assess the amount of water.

Comment: Oh, strange that my teacher didn't include that!

Comment: The argon only adds 0.4 to the average molecular weight, so it is not a big deal.  But your percentages don't add to $100\%$, which is why I noted it.

Comment: If you're here..

I'm trying to calculate this 919 meters up thing and I say:

$$p=101000 \cdot e^{\frac{28.56 \cdot 9.8 \cdot 919}{6.02 \cdot 1.3 \cdot T}}$$

I don't include $10^{23}$ and $10^{-23}$ in avogadro and boltzmann as they must cancel. I'm not sure what $T$ is supposed to be but I just get *overflow* on my calculator...

Comment: The $T$ is the absolute temperature.  You are assuming the atmosphere is isothermal.  It should be something like $300$.  The other problem is you still forgot the minus sign.  The pressure should decrease with altitude.

Comment: @RossMillikan Why can't I directly substitute P=hρg in the gas equation?

Comment: @Shub:  $\rho$ is not a constant, and that shows $P$=0 at $h=0$.